# How can I evaluate my sequence prediction model?

Tags: python, keras, prediction, model-evaluations

I want to evaluate the performance of my prediction model , which is an VED (Variational Encoder Decoder) used for sequences prediction (it predicts the next sequence knowing the actual)
I want to evaluate the model by calculating the similarity between the input sequence (x_train) and the predicted one.

I found that there is a score called BELU can be used for this, but I'm not sure.
If someone has an idea, please help me .

Comment: Sequences could be seen as vectors. See [here](http://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/) for measures used for calculating the similarity of vectors. Also, BLEU could be used as mentioned [here](http://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/).

Comment: thank you, but the links are for the same page, I think the second one is not the right link